# Disminuir sangrado de la etiqueta <pre>

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo un pequeño HTML en el que alojo unos tantos codigos Python, entonces para colorear la sintaxis y eso me he valido de la siguiente **libreria Javascript**: [Prism](https://prismjs.com/index.html)

Funciona bastante bien, sin embargo me encuentro con el siguiente problema:

```js
/* PrismJS 1.19.0
https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-tomorrow&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript+python+sql&plugins=toolbar */
var _self="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof WorkerGlobalScope&&self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope?self:{},Prism=function(u){var c=/\blang(?:uage)?-([\w-]+)\b/i,r=0,C={manual:u.Prism&&u.Prism.manual,disableWorkerMessageHandler:u.Prism&&u.Prism.disableWorkerMessageHandler,util:{encode:function e(r){return r instanceof _?new _(r.type,e(r.content),r.alias):Array.isArray(r)?r.map(e):r.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/\u00a0/g," ")},type:function(e){return Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8,-1)},objId:function(e){return e.__id||Object.defineProperty(e,"__id",{value:++r}),e.__id},clone:function n(e,t){var a,r,i=C.util.type(e);switch(t=t||{},i){case"Object":if(r=C.util.objId(e),t[r])return t[r];for(var o in a={},t[r]=a,e)e.hasOwnProperty(o)&&(a[o]=n(e[o],t));return a;case"Array":return r=C.util.objId(e),t[r]?t[r]:(a=[],t[r]=a,e.forEach(function(e,r){a[r]=n(e,t)}),a);default:return e}},getLanguage:function(e){for(;e&&!c.test(e.className);)e=e.parentElement;return e?(e.className.match(c)||[,"none"])[1].toLowerCase():"none"},currentScript:function(){if("undefined"==typeof document)return null;if("currentScript"in document)return document.currentScript;try{throw new Error}catch(e){var r=(/at [^(\r\n]*\((.*):.+:.+\)$/i.exec(e.stack)||[])[1];if(r){var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script");for(var t in n)if(n[t].src==r)return n[t]}return null}}},languages:{extend:function(e,r){var n=C.util.clone(C.languages[e]);for(var t in r)n[t]=r[t];return n},insertBefore:function(n,e,r,t){var a=(t=t||C.languages)[n],i={};for(var o in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(o)){if(o==e)for(var l in r)r.hasOwnProperty(l)&&(i[l]=r[l]);r.hasOwnProperty(o)||(i[o]=a[o])}var s=t[n];return t[n]=i,C.languages.DFS(C.languages,function(e,r){r===s&&e!=n&&(this[e]=i)}),i},DFS:function e(r,n,t,a){a=a||{};var i=C.util.objId;for(var o in r)if(r.hasOwnProperty(o)){n.call(r,o,r[o],t||o);var l=r[o],s=C.util.type(l);"Object"!==s||a[i(l)]?"Array"!==s||a[i(l)]||(a[i(l)]=!0,e(l,n,o,a)):(a[i(l)]=!0,e(l,n,null,a))}}},plugins:{},highlightAll:function(e,r){C.highlightAllUnder(document,e,r)},highlightAllUnder:function(e,r,n){var t={callback:n,container:e,selector:'code[class*="language-"], [class*="language-"] code, code[class*="lang-"], [class*="lang-"] code'};C.hooks.run("before-highlightall",t),t.elements=Array.prototype.slice.apply(t.container.querySelectorAll(t.selector)),C.hooks.run("before-all-elements-highlight",t);for(var a,i=0;a=t.elements[i++];)C.highlightElement(a,!0===r,t.callback)},highlightElement:function(e,r,n){var t=C.util.getLanguage(e),a=C.languages[t];e.className=e.className.replace(c,"").replace(/\s+/g," ")+" language-"+t;var i=e.parentNode;i&&"pre"===i.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&(i.className=i.className.replace(c,"").replace(/\s+/g," ")+" language-"+t);var o={element:e,language:t,grammar:a,code:e.textContent};function l(e){o.highlightedCode=e,C.hooks.run("before-insert",o),o.element.innerHTML=o.highlightedCode,C.hooks.run("after-highlight",o),C.hooks.run("complete",o),n&&n.call(o.element)}if(C.hooks.run("before-sanity-check",o),!o.code)return C.hooks.run("complete",o),void(n&&n.call(o.element));if(C.hooks.run("before-highlight",o),o.grammar)if(r&&u.Worker){var s=new Worker(C.filename);s.onmessage=function(e){l(e.data)},s.postMessage(JSON.stringify({language:o.language,code:o.code,immediateClose:!0}))}else l(C.highlight(o.code,o.grammar,o.language));else l(C.util.encode(o.code))},highlight:function(e,r,n){var t={code:e,grammar:r,language:n};return C.hooks.run("before-tokenize",t),t.tokens=C.tokenize(t.code,t.grammar),C.hooks.run("after-tokenize",t),_.stringify(C.util.encode(t.tokens),t.language)},matchGrammar:function(e,r,n,t,a,i,o){for(var l in n)if(n.hasOwnProperty(l)&&n[l]){var s=n[l];s=Array.isArray(s)?s:[s];for(var u=0;u<s.length;++u){if(o&&o==l+","+u)return;var c=s[u],g=c.inside,f=!!c.lookbehind,h=!!c.greedy,d=0,m=c.alias;if(h&&!c.pattern.global){var p=c.pattern.toString().match(/[imsuy]*$/)[0];c.pattern=RegExp(c.pattern.source,p+"g")}c=c.pattern||c;for(var y=t,v=a;y<r.length;v+=r[y].length,++y){var k=r[y];if(r.length>e.length)return;if(!(k instanceof _)){if(h&&y!=r.length-1){if(c.lastIndex=v,!(S=c.exec(e)))break;for(var b=S.index+(f&&S[1]?S[1].length:0),w=S.index+S[0].length,A=y,P=v,x=r.length;A<x&&(P<w||!r[A].type&&!r[A-1].greedy);++A)(P+=r[A].length)<=b&&(++y,v=P);if(r[y]instanceof _)continue;O=A-y,k=e.slice(v,P),S.index-=v}else{c.lastIndex=0;var S=c.exec(k),O=1}if(S){f&&(d=S[1]?S[1].length:0);w=(b=S.index+d)+(S=S[0].slice(d)).length;var E=k.slice(0,b),N=k.slice(w),j=[y,O];E&&(++y,v+=E.length,j.push(E));var L=new _(l,g?C.tokenize(S,g):S,m,S,h);if(j.push(L),N&&j.push(N),Array.prototype.splice.apply(r,j),1!=O&&C.matchGrammar(e,r,n,y,v,!0,l+","+u),i)break}else if(i)break}}}}},tokenize:function(e,r){var n=[e],t=r.rest;if(t){for(var a in t)r[a]=t[a];delete r.rest}return C.matchGrammar(e,n,r,0,0,!1),n},hooks:{all:{},add:function(e,r){var n=C.hooks.all;n[e]=n[e]||[],n[e].push(r)},run:function(e,r){var n=C.hooks.all[e];if(n&&n.length)for(var t,a=0;t=n[a++];)t(r)}},Token:_};function _(e,r,n,t,a){this.type=e,this.content=r,this.alias=n,this.length=0|(t||"").length,this.greedy=!!a}if(u.Prism=C,_.stringify=function r(e,n){if("string"==typeof e)return e;if(Array.isArray(e)){var t="";return e.forEach(function(e){t+=r(e,n)}),t}var a={type:e.type,content:r(e.content,n),tag:"span",classes:["token",e.type],attributes:{},language:n},i=e.alias;i&&(Array.isArray(i)?Array.prototype.push.apply(a.classes,i):a.classes.push(i)),C.hooks.run("wrap",a);var o="";for(var l in a.attributes)o+=" "+l+'="'+(a.attributes[l]||"").replace(/"/g,"&quot;")+'"';return"<"+a.tag+' class="'+a.classes.join(" ")+'"'+o+">"+a.content+"</"+a.tag+">"},!u.document)return u.addEventListener&&(C.disableWorkerMessageHandler||u.addEventListener("message",function(e){var r=JSON.parse(e.data),n=r.language,t=r.code,a=r.immediateClose;u.postMessage(C.highlight(t,C.languages[n],n)),a&&u.close()},!1)),C;var e=C.util.currentScript();function n(){C.manual||C.highlightAll()}if(e&&(C.filename=e.src,e.hasAttribute("data-manual")&&(C.manual=!0)),!C.manual){var t=document.readyState;"loading"===t||"interactive"===t&&e&&e.defer?document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n):window.requestAnimationFrame?window.requestAnimationFrame(n):window.setTimeout(n,16)}return C}(_self);"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=Prism),"undefined"!=typeof global&&(global.Prism=Prism);
Prism.languages.markup={comment:/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/,prolog:/<\?[\s\S]+?\?>/,doctype:{pattern:/<!DOCTYPE(?:[^>"'[\]]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+(?:\[(?:(?!<!--)[^"'\]]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|<!--[\s\S]*?-->)*\]\s*)?>/i,greedy:!0},cdata:/<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?]]>/i,tag:{pattern:/<\/?(?!\d)[^\s>\/=$<%]+(?:\s(?:\s*[^\s>\/=]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s'">=]+(?=[\s>]))|(?=[\s/>])))+)?\s*\/?>/i,greedy:!0,inside:{tag:{pattern:/^<\/?[^\s>\/]+/i,inside:{punctuation:/^<\/?/,namespace:/^[^\s>\/:]+:/}},"attr-value":{pattern:/=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s'">=]+)/i,inside:{punctuation:[/^=/,{pattern:/^(\s*)["']|["']$/,lookbehind:!0}]}},punctuation:/\/?>/,"attr-name":{pattern:/[^\s>\/]+/,inside:{namespace:/^[^\s>\/:]+:/}}}},entity:/&#?[\da-z]{1,8};/i},Prism.languages.markup.tag.inside["attr-value"].inside.entity=Prism.languages.markup.entity,Prism.hooks.add("wrap",function(a){"entity"===a.type&&(a.attributes.title=a.content.replace(/&amp;/,"&"))}),Object.defineProperty(Prism.languages.markup.tag,"addInlined",{value:function(a,e){var s={};s["language-"+e]={pattern:/(^<!\[CDATA\[)[\s\S]+?(?=\]\]>$)/i,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages[e]},s.cdata=/^<!\[CDATA\[|\]\]>$/i;var n={"included-cdata":{pattern:/<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?\]\]>/i,inside:s}};n["language-"+e]={pattern:/[\s\S]+/,inside:Prism.languages[e]};var t={};t[a]={pattern:RegExp("(<__[\\s\\S]*?>)(?:<!\\[CDATA\\[[\\s\\S]*?\\]\\]>\\s*|[\\s\\S])*?(?=<\\/__>)".replace(/__/g,a),"i"),lookbehind:!0,greedy:!0,inside:n},Prism.languages.insertBefore("markup","cdata",t)}}),Prism.languages.xml=Prism.languages.extend("markup",{}),Prism.languages.html=Prism.languages.markup,Prism.languages.mathml=Prism.languages.markup,Prism.languages.svg=Prism.languages.markup;
!function(s){var e=/("|')(?:\\(?:\r\n|[\s\S])|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/;s.languages.css={comment:/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//,atrule:{pattern:/@[\w-]+[\s\S]*?(?:;|(?=\s*\{))/,inside:{rule:/^@[\w-]+/,"selector-function-argument":{pattern:/(\bselector\s*\((?!\s*\))\s*)(?:[^()]|\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\))+?(?=\s*\))/,lookbehind:!0,alias:"selector"}}},url:{pattern:RegExp("url\\((?:"+e.source+"|[^\n\r()]*)\\)","i"),inside:{function:/^url/i,punctuation:/^\(|\)$/}},selector:RegExp("[^{}\\s](?:[^{};\"']|"+e.source+")*?(?=\\s*\\{)"),string:{pattern:e,greedy:!0},property:/[-_a-z\xA0-\uFFFF][-\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*:)/i,important:/!important\b/i,function:/[-a-z0-9]+(?=\()/i,punctuation:/[(){};:,]/},s.languages.css.atrule.inside.rest=s.languages.css;var t=s.languages.markup;t&&(t.tag.addInlined("style","css"),s.languages.insertBefore("inside","attr-value",{"style-attr":{pattern:/\s*style=("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1/i,inside:{"attr-name":{pattern:/^\s*style/i,inside:t.tag.inside},punctuation:/^\s*=\s*['"]|['"]\s*$/,"attr-value":{pattern:/.+/i,inside:s.languages.css}},alias:"language-css"}},t.tag))}(Prism);
Prism.languages.clike={comment:[{pattern:/(^|[^\\])\/\*[\s\S]*?(?:\*\/|$)/,lookbehind:!0},{pattern:/(^|[^\\:])\/\/.*/,lookbehind:!0,greedy:!0}],string:{pattern:/(["'])(?:\\(?:\r\n|[\s\S])|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/,greedy:!0},"class-name":{pattern:/(\b(?:class|interface|extends|implements|trait|instanceof|new)\s+|\bcatch\s+\()[\w.\\]+/i,lookbehind:!0,inside:{punctuation:/[.\\]/}},keyword:/\b(?:if|else|while|do|for|return|in|instanceof|function|new|try|throw|catch|finally|null|break|continue)\b/,boolean:/\b(?:true|false)\b/,function:/\w+(?=\()/,number:/\b0x[\da-f]+\b|(?:\b\d+\.?\d*|\B\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?/i,operator:/[<>]=?|[!=]=?=?|--?|\+\+?|&&?|\|\|?|[?*/~^%]/,punctuation:/[{}[\];(),.:]/};
Prism.languages.javascript=Prism.languages.extend("clike",{"class-name":[Prism.languages.clike["class-name"],{pattern:/(^|[^$\w\xA0-\uFFFF])[_$A-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\.(?:prototype|constructor))/,lookbehind:!0}],keyword:[{pattern:/((?:^|})\s*)(?:catch|finally)\b/,lookbehind:!0},{pattern:/(^|[^.]|\.\.\.\s*)\b(?:as|async(?=\s*(?:function\b|\(|[$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]|$))|await|break|case|class|const|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|else|enum|export|extends|for|from|function|get|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|interface|let|new|null|of|package|private|protected|public|return|set|static|super|switch|this|throw|try|typeof|undefined|var|void|while|with|yield)\b/,lookbehind:!0}],number:/\b(?:(?:0[xX](?:[\dA-Fa-f](?:_[\dA-Fa-f])?)+|0[bB](?:[01](?:_[01])?)+|0[oO](?:[0-7](?:_[0-7])?)+)n?|(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+n|NaN|Infinity)\b|(?:\b(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+\.?(?:\d(?:_\d)?)*|\B\.(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+)(?:[Ee][+-]?(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+)?/,function:/#?[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*(?:\.\s*(?:apply|bind|call)\s*)?\()/,operator:/--|\+\+|\*\*=?|=>|&&|\|\||[!=]==|<<=?|>>>?=?|[-+*/%&|^!=<>]=?|\.{3}|\?[.?]?|[~:]/}),Prism.languages.javascript["class-name"][0].pattern=/(\b(?:class|interface|extends|implements|instanceof|new)\s+)[\w.\\]+/,Prism.languages.insertBefore("javascript","keyword",{regex:{pattern:/((?:^|[^$\w\xA0-\uFFFF."'\])\s])\s*)\/(?:\[(?:[^\]\\\r\n]|\\.)*]|\\.|[^/\\\[\r\n])+\/[gimyus]{0,6}(?=(?:\s|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)*(?:$|[\r\n,.;:})\]]|\/\/))/,lookbehind:!0,greedy:!0},"function-variable":{pattern:/#?[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*[=:]\s*(?:async\s*)?(?:\bfunction\b|(?:\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\)|[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*)\s*=>))/,alias:"function"},parameter:[{pattern:/(function(?:\s+[_$A-Za-z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*)?\s*\(\s*)(?!\s)(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))+?(?=\s*\))/,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages.javascript},{pattern:/[_$a-z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*=>)/i,inside:Prism.languages.javascript},{pattern:/(\(\s*)(?!\s)(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))+?(?=\s*\)\s*=>)/,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages.javascript},{pattern:/((?:\b|\s|^)(?!(?:as|async|await|break|case|catch|class|const|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|else|enum|export|extends|finally|for|from|function|get|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|interface|let|new|null|of|package|private|protected|public|return|set|static|super|switch|this|throw|try|typeof|undefined|var|void|while|with|yield)(?![$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]))(?:[_$A-Za-z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*\s*)\(\s*)(?!\s)(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))+?(?=\s*\)\s*\{)/,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages.javascript}],constant:/\b[A-Z](?:[A-Z_]|\dx?)*\b/}),Prism.languages.insertBefore("javascript","string",{"template-string":{pattern:/`(?:\\[\s\S]|\${(?:[^{}]|{(?:[^{}]|{[^}]*})*})+}|(?!\${)[^\\`])*`/,greedy:!0,inside:{"template-punctuation":{pattern:/^`|`$/,alias:"string"},interpolation:{pattern:/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)\${(?:[^{}]|{(?:[^{}]|{[^}]*})*})+}/,lookbehind:!0,inside:{"interpolation-punctuation":{pattern:/^\${|}$/,alias:"punctuation"},rest:Prism.languages.javascript}},string:/[\s\S]+/}}}),Prism.languages.markup&&Prism.languages.markup.tag.addInlined("script","javascript"),Prism.languages.js=Prism.languages.javascript;
Prism.languages.python={comment:{pattern:/(^|[^\\])#.*/,lookbehind:!0},"string-interpolation":{pattern:/(?:f|rf|fr)(?:("""|''')[\s\S]+?\1|("|')(?:\\.|(?!\2)[^\\\r\n])*\2)/i,greedy:!0,inside:{interpolation:{pattern:/((?:^|[^{])(?:{{)*){(?!{)(?:[^{}]|{(?!{)(?:[^{}]|{(?!{)(?:[^{}])+})+})+}/,lookbehind:!0,inside:{"format-spec":{pattern:/(:)[^:(){}]+(?=}$)/,lookbehind:!0},"conversion-option":{pattern:/![sra](?=[:}]$)/,alias:"punctuation"},rest:null}},string:/[\s\S]+/}},"triple-quoted-string":{pattern:/(?:[rub]|rb|br)?("""|''')[\s\S]+?\1/i,greedy:!0,alias:"string"},string:{pattern:/(?:[rub]|rb|br)?("|')(?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/i,greedy:!0},function:{pattern:/((?:^|\s)def[ \t]+)[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?=\s*\()/g,lookbehind:!0},"class-name":{pattern:/(\bclass\s+)\w+/i,lookbehind:!0},decorator:{pattern:/(^\s*)@\w+(?:\.\w+)*/im,lookbehind:!0,alias:["annotation","punctuation"],inside:{punctuation:/\./}},keyword:/\b(?:and|as|assert|async|await|break|class|continue|def|del|elif|else|except|exec|finally|for|from|global|if|import|in|is|lambda|nonlocal|not|or|pass|print|raise|return|try|while|with|yield)\b/,builtin:/\b(?:__import__|abs|all|any|apply|ascii|basestring|bin|bool|buffer|bytearray|bytes|callable|chr|classmethod|cmp|coerce|compile|complex|delattr|dict|dir|divmod|enumerate|eval|execfile|file|filter|float|format|frozenset|getattr|globals|hasattr|hash|help|hex|id|input|int|intern|isinstance|issubclass|iter|len|list|locals|long|map|max|memoryview|min|next|object|oct|open|ord|pow|property|range|raw_input|reduce|reload|repr|reversed|round|set|setattr|slice|sorted|staticmethod|str|sum|super|tuple|type|unichr|unicode|vars|xrange|zip)\b/,boolean:/\b(?:True|False|None)\b/,number:/(?:\b(?=\d)|\B(?=\.))(?:0[bo])?(?:(?:\d|0x[\da-f])[\da-f]*\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?j?\b/i,operator:/[-+%=]=?|!=|\*\*?=?|\/\/?=?|<[<=>]?|>[=>]?|[&|^~]/,punctuation:/[{}[\];(),.:]/},Prism.languages.python["string-interpolation"].inside.interpolation.inside.rest=Prism.languages.python,Prism.languages.py=Prism.languages.python;
Prism.languages.sql={comment:{pattern:/(^|[^\\])(?:\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(?:--|\/\/|#).*)/,lookbehind:!0},variable:[{pattern:/@(["'`])(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])+\1/,greedy:!0},/@[\w.$]+/],string:{pattern:/(^|[^@\\])("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\2)[^\\]|\2\2)*\2/,greedy:!0,lookbehind:!0},function:/\b(?:AVG|COUNT|FIRST|FORMAT|LAST|LCASE|LEN|MAX|MID|MIN|MOD|NOW|ROUND|SUM|UCASE)(?=\s*\()/i,keyword:/\b(?:ACTION|ADD|AFTER|ALGORITHM|ALL|ALTER|ANALYZE|ANY|APPLY|AS|ASC|AUTHORIZATION|AUTO_INCREMENT|BACKUP|BDB|BEGIN|BERKELEYDB|BIGINT|BINARY|BIT|BLOB|BOOL|BOOLEAN|BREAK|BROWSE|BTREE|BULK|BY|CALL|CASCADED?|CASE|CHAIN|CHAR(?:ACTER|SET)?|CHECK(?:POINT)?|CLOSE|CLUSTERED|COALESCE|COLLATE|COLUMNS?|COMMENT|COMMIT(?:TED)?|COMPUTE|CONNECT|CONSISTENT|CONSTRAINT|CONTAINS(?:TABLE)?|CONTINUE|CONVERT|CREATE|CROSS|CURRENT(?:_DATE|_TIME|_TIMESTAMP|_USER)?|CURSOR|CYCLE|DATA(?:BASES?)?|DATE(?:TIME)?|DAY|DBCC|DEALLOCATE|DEC|DECIMAL|DECLARE|DEFAULT|DEFINER|DELAYED|DELETE|DELIMITERS?|DENY|DESC|DESCRIBE|DETERMINISTIC|DISABLE|DISCARD|DISK|DISTINCT|DISTINCTROW|DISTRIBUTED|DO|DOUBLE|DROP|DUMMY|DUMP(?:FILE)?|DUPLICATE|ELSE(?:IF)?|ENABLE|ENCLOSED|END|ENGINE|ENUM|ERRLVL|ERRORS|ESCAPED?|EXCEPT|EXEC(?:UTE)?|EXISTS|EXIT|EXPLAIN|EXTENDED|FETCH|FIELDS|FILE|FILLFACTOR|FIRST|FIXED|FLOAT|FOLLOWING|FOR(?: EACH ROW)?|FORCE|FOREIGN|FREETEXT(?:TABLE)?|FROM|FULL|FUNCTION|GEOMETRY(?:COLLECTION)?|GLOBAL|GOTO|GRANT|GROUP|HANDLER|HASH|HAVING|HOLDLOCK|HOUR|IDENTITY(?:_INSERT|COL)?|IF|IGNORE|IMPORT|INDEX|INFILE|INNER|INNODB|INOUT|INSERT|INT|INTEGER|INTERSECT|INTERVAL|INTO|INVOKER|ISOLATION|ITERATE|JOIN|KEYS?|KILL|LANGUAGE|LAST|LEAVE|LEFT|LEVEL|LIMIT|LINENO|LINES|LINESTRING|LOAD|LOCAL|LOCK|LONG(?:BLOB|TEXT)|LOOP|MATCH(?:ED)?|MEDIUM(?:BLOB|INT|TEXT)|MERGE|MIDDLEINT|MINUTE|MODE|MODIFIES|MODIFY|MONTH|MULTI(?:LINESTRING|POINT|POLYGON)|NATIONAL|NATURAL|NCHAR|NEXT|NO|NONCLUSTERED|NULLIF|NUMERIC|OFF?|OFFSETS?|ON|OPEN(?:DATASOURCE|QUERY|ROWSET)?|OPTIMIZE|OPTION(?:ALLY)?|ORDER|OUT(?:ER|FILE)?|OVER|PARTIAL|PARTITION|PERCENT|PIVOT|PLAN|POINT|POLYGON|PRECEDING|PRECISION|PREPARE|PREV|PRIMARY|PRINT|PRIVILEGES|PROC(?:EDURE)?|PUBLIC|PURGE|QUICK|RAISERROR|READS?|REAL|RECONFIGURE|REFERENCES|RELEASE|RENAME|REPEAT(?:ABLE)?|REPLACE|REPLICATION|REQUIRE|RESIGNAL|RESTORE|RESTRICT|RETURNS?|REVOKE|RIGHT|ROLLBACK|ROUTINE|ROW(?:COUNT|GUIDCOL|S)?|RTREE|RULE|SAVE(?:POINT)?|SCHEMA|SECOND|SELECT|SERIAL(?:IZABLE)?|SESSION(?:_USER)?|SET(?:USER)?|SHARE|SHOW|SHUTDOWN|SIMPLE|SMALLINT|SNAPSHOT|SOME|SONAME|SQL|START(?:ING)?|STATISTICS|STATUS|STRIPED|SYSTEM_USER|TABLES?|TABLESPACE|TEMP(?:ORARY|TABLE)?|TERMINATED|TEXT(?:SIZE)?|THEN|TIME(?:STAMP)?|TINY(?:BLOB|INT|TEXT)|TOP?|TRAN(?:SACTIONS?)?|TRIGGER|TRUNCATE|TSEQUAL|TYPES?|UNBOUNDED|UNCOMMITTED|UNDEFINED|UNION|UNIQUE|UNLOCK|UNPIVOT|UNSIGNED|UPDATE(?:TEXT)?|USAGE|USE|USER|USING|VALUES?|VAR(?:BINARY|CHAR|CHARACTER|YING)|VIEW|WAITFOR|WARNINGS|WHEN|WHERE|WHILE|WITH(?: ROLLUP|IN)?|WORK|WRITE(?:TEXT)?|YEAR)\b/i,boolean:/\b(?:TRUE|FALSE|NULL)\b/i,number:/\b0x[\da-f]+\b|\b\d+\.?\d*|\B\.\d+\b/i,operator:/[-+*\/=%^~]|&&?|\|\|?|!=?|<(?:=>?|<|>)?|>[>=]?|\b(?:AND|BETWEEN|IN|LIKE|NOT|OR|IS|DIV|REGEXP|RLIKE|SOUNDS LIKE|XOR)\b/i,punctuation:/[;[\]()`,.]/};
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document){var i=[],l={},c=function(){};Prism.plugins.toolbar={};var e=Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton=function(e,n){var t;t="function"==typeof n?n:function(e){var t;return"function"==typeof n.onClick?((t=document.createElement("button")).type="button",t.addEventListener("click",function(){n.onClick.call(this,e)})):"string"==typeof n.url?(t=document.createElement("a")).href=n.url:t=document.createElement("span"),n.className&&t.classList.add(n.className),t.textContent=n.text,t},e in l?console.warn('There is a button with the key "'+e+'" registered already.'):i.push(l[e]=t)},t=Prism.plugins.toolbar.hook=function(a){var e=a.element.parentNode;if(e&&/pre/i.test(e.nodeName)&&!e.parentNode.classList.contains("code-toolbar")){var t=document.createElement("div");t.classList.add("code-toolbar"),e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e),t.appendChild(e);var r=document.createElement("div");r.classList.add("toolbar");var n=i,o=function(e){for(;e;){var t=e.getAttribute("data-toolbar-order");if(null!=t)return(t=t.trim()).length?t.split(/\s*,\s*/g):[];e=e.parentElement}}(a.element);o&&(n=o.map(function(e){return l[e]||c})),n.forEach(function(e){var t=e(a);if(t){var n=document.createElement("div");n.classList.add("toolbar-item"),n.appendChild(t),r.appendChild(n)}}),t.appendChild(r)}};e("label",function(e){var t=e.element.parentNode;if(t&&/pre/i.test(t.nodeName)&&t.hasAttribute("data-label")){var n,a,r=t.getAttribute("data-label");try{a=document.querySelector("template#"+r)}catch(e){}return a?n=a.content:(t.hasAttribute("data-url")?(n=document.createElement("a")).href=t.getAttribute("data-url"):n=document.createElement("span"),n.textContent=r),n}}),Prism.hooks.add("complete",t)}}();
```

```css
/* PrismJS 1.19.0
https://prismjs.com/download.html#themes=prism-tomorrow&languages=markup+css+clike+javascript+python+sql&plugins=toolbar */
/**
 * prism.js tomorrow night eighties for JavaScript, CoffeeScript, CSS and HTML
 * Based on https://github.com/chriskempson/tomorrow-theme
 * @author Rose Pritchard
 */

code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
 color: #ccc;
 background: none;
 font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: left;
 white-space: pre;
 word-spacing: normal;
 word-break: normal;
 word-wrap: normal;
 line-height: 1.5;

 -moz-tab-size: 4;
 -o-tab-size: 4;
 tab-size: 4;

 -webkit-hyphens: none;
 -moz-hyphens: none;
 -ms-hyphens: none;
 hyphens: none;

}

/* Code blocks */
pre[class*="language-"] {
 /*padding: 1em;*/
 margin: .5em 0;
 overflow: auto;
}

:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
 background: #2d2d2d;
}

/* Inline code */
:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
 padding: .1em;
 border-radius: .3em;
 white-space: normal;
}

.token.comment,
.token.block-comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.doctype,
.token.cdata {
 color: #999;
}

.token.punctuation {
 color: #ccc;
}

.token.tag,
.token.attr-name,
.token.namespace,
.token.deleted {
 color: #e2777a;
}

.token.function-name {
 color: #6196cc;
}

.token.boolean,
.token.number,
.token.function {
 color: #f08d49;
}

.token.property,
.token.class-name,
.token.constant,
.token.symbol {
 color: #f8c555;
}

.token.selector,
.token.important,
.token.atrule,
.token.keyword,
.token.builtin {
 color: #cc99cd;
}

.token.string,
.token.char,
.token.attr-value,
.token.regex,
.token.variable {
 color: #7ec699;
}

.token.operator,
.token.entity,
.token.url {
 color: #67cdcc;
}

.token.important,
.token.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.token.italic {
 font-style: italic;
}

.token.entity {
 cursor: help;
}

.token.inserted {
 color: green;
}

div.code-toolbar {
 position: relative;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar {
 position: absolute;
 top: .3em;
 right: .2em;
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
}

div.code-toolbar:hover > .toolbar {
 opacity: 1;
}

/* Separate line b/c rules are thrown out if selector is invalid.
   IE11 and old Edge versions don't support :focus-within. */
div.code-toolbar:focus-within > .toolbar {
 opacity: 1;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar .toolbar-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a {
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button {
 background: none;
 border: 0;
 color: inherit;
 font: inherit;
 line-height: normal;
 overflow: visible;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* for button */
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar span {
 color: #bbb;
 font-size: .8em;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background: #f5f2f0;
 background: rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: .5em;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a:hover,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a:focus,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button:hover,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button:focus,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar span:hover,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar span:focus {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="expresiones" class="clasificacion">
   <h1>EXPRESIONES</h1>
   <pre>
    <code class="language-python">
    if x < 0:
     x = 0
     print('Negativo cambiado a cero')
    elif x == 0:
     print('Cero')
    elif x == 1:
     print('Simple')
    else:
      print('Más')
    </code>
   </pre>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

El codigo tiene demasiado sangrado. He estado haciendo pruebas y me he dado cuenta de que ese sangrado **es el mismo que yo tenga en mi codigo HTML**, sin embargo ese sangrado es necesario para **tener el codigo organizado** ¿No? Porque para que quede bien tendria que alinear el codigo HTML más a la izquierda y la verdad no me convence porque me gusta tener bien identado mi codigo. Entonces, la pregunta final seria, **¿Como hago para que la etiqueta  no me tome todo el sangrado que está en el codigo HTML?** O **cómo disminuirlo**. He intentado hacerlo desde **CSS** apuntando directamente a la eqtiqueta **pre** y moviendo los valores de **padding**, **margin-left**, pero nada.

Comment: Necesitas este plugin: https://prismjs.com/plugins/normalize-whitespace/

Comment: @alanfcm Había leido el apartado de Plugins pero por alguna razón no vi ese, funcionó a la perfección hermano, gracias. Una ultima cosa, ¿Como se haría para activar un tipo de ajuste de linea? Para evitar la barra que sale cuando el texto se hace muy largo.

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/k3c4ghq7/ Lo que sucede es que al HTML le he modificado el **margin** para que el contenido quede más compacto. En el ejemplo de código se lo he comentado (está en el HTML) porque se sumaba al margen que coloca la pagina y se reducía demasiado, en todo caso, esa es la barraque quisiera quitar.

Comment: La unica forma de cambiarlo seria cambiando esta linea: `overflow: auto;` a `overflow: hidden;`, pero eso te va a cortar el codigo.  Tambien podrias partir tu codigo en varias lineas donde necesites para evitar el scroll.

Comment: Sí, tienes razón, imagino que hay que jugar un poco con el css, gracias de igual manera. Se puede dar el problema principal como solucionado.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes dentro de la clase de 'css' que da estilo al 'pre' un 'tab-size' que marca la distancia en el número de tabulaciones que debe dejar el código. Cambiando esta propiedad consigues moverlo a derecha e izquierda en función de las necesidades de tu código:

Tu tenías:

```
pre[class*="language-"] {
    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    -o-tab-size: 4;
    tab-size: 4;
}
```

Cambiándolo a 1 puedes ver el resultado ejecutando aquí tu propio código:

```
pre[class*="language-"] {
    -moz-tab-size: 1;
    -o-tab-size: 1;
    tab-size: 1;
}
```

```js
var _self="undefined"!=typeof window?window:"undefined"!=typeof WorkerGlobalScope&&self instanceof WorkerGlobalScope?self:{},Prism=function(u){var c=/\blang(?:uage)?-([\w-]+)\b/i,r=0,C={manual:u.Prism&&u.Prism.manual,disableWorkerMessageHandler:u.Prism&&u.Prism.disableWorkerMessageHandler,util:{encode:function e(r){return r instanceof _?new _(r.type,e(r.content),r.alias):Array.isArray(r)?r.map(e):r.replace(/&/g,"&amp;").replace(/</g,"&lt;").replace(/\u00a0/g," ")},type:function(e){return Object.prototype.toString.call(e).slice(8,-1)},objId:function(e){return e.__id||Object.defineProperty(e,"__id",{value:++r}),e.__id},clone:function n(e,t){var a,r,i=C.util.type(e);switch(t=t||{},i){case"Object":if(r=C.util.objId(e),t[r])return t[r];for(var o in a={},t[r]=a,e)e.hasOwnProperty(o)&&(a[o]=n(e[o],t));return a;case"Array":return r=C.util.objId(e),t[r]?t[r]:(a=[],t[r]=a,e.forEach(function(e,r){a[r]=n(e,t)}),a);default:return e}},getLanguage:function(e){for(;e&&!c.test(e.className);)e=e.parentElement;return e?(e.className.match(c)||[,"none"])[1].toLowerCase():"none"},currentScript:function(){if("undefined"==typeof document)return null;if("currentScript"in document)return document.currentScript;try{throw new Error}catch(e){var r=(/at [^(\r\n]*\((.*):.+:.+\)$/i.exec(e.stack)||[])[1];if(r){var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script");for(var t in n)if(n[t].src==r)return n[t]}return null}}},languages:{extend:function(e,r){var n=C.util.clone(C.languages[e]);for(var t in r)n[t]=r[t];return n},insertBefore:function(n,e,r,t){var a=(t=t||C.languages)[n],i={};for(var o in a)if(a.hasOwnProperty(o)){if(o==e)for(var l in r)r.hasOwnProperty(l)&&(i[l]=r[l]);r.hasOwnProperty(o)||(i[o]=a[o])}var s=t[n];return t[n]=i,C.languages.DFS(C.languages,function(e,r){r===s&&e!=n&&(this[e]=i)}),i},DFS:function e(r,n,t,a){a=a||{};var i=C.util.objId;for(var o in r)if(r.hasOwnProperty(o)){n.call(r,o,r[o],t||o);var l=r[o],s=C.util.type(l);"Object"!==s||a[i(l)]?"Array"!==s||a[i(l)]||(a[i(l)]=!0,e(l,n,o,a)):(a[i(l)]=!0,e(l,n,null,a))}}},plugins:{},highlightAll:function(e,r){C.highlightAllUnder(document,e,r)},highlightAllUnder:function(e,r,n){var t={callback:n,container:e,selector:'code[class*="language-"], [class*="language-"] code, code[class*="lang-"], [class*="lang-"] code'};C.hooks.run("before-highlightall",t),t.elements=Array.prototype.slice.apply(t.container.querySelectorAll(t.selector)),C.hooks.run("before-all-elements-highlight",t);for(var a,i=0;a=t.elements[i++];)C.highlightElement(a,!0===r,t.callback)},highlightElement:function(e,r,n){var t=C.util.getLanguage(e),a=C.languages[t];e.className=e.className.replace(c,"").replace(/\s+/g," ")+" language-"+t;var i=e.parentNode;i&&"pre"===i.nodeName.toLowerCase()&&(i.className=i.className.replace(c,"").replace(/\s+/g," ")+" language-"+t);var o={element:e,language:t,grammar:a,code:e.textContent};function l(e){o.highlightedCode=e,C.hooks.run("before-insert",o),o.element.innerHTML=o.highlightedCode,C.hooks.run("after-highlight",o),C.hooks.run("complete",o),n&&n.call(o.element)}if(C.hooks.run("before-sanity-check",o),!o.code)return C.hooks.run("complete",o),void(n&&n.call(o.element));if(C.hooks.run("before-highlight",o),o.grammar)if(r&&u.Worker){var s=new Worker(C.filename);s.onmessage=function(e){l(e.data)},s.postMessage(JSON.stringify({language:o.language,code:o.code,immediateClose:!0}))}else l(C.highlight(o.code,o.grammar,o.language));else l(C.util.encode(o.code))},highlight:function(e,r,n){var t={code:e,grammar:r,language:n};return C.hooks.run("before-tokenize",t),t.tokens=C.tokenize(t.code,t.grammar),C.hooks.run("after-tokenize",t),_.stringify(C.util.encode(t.tokens),t.language)},matchGrammar:function(e,r,n,t,a,i,o){for(var l in n)if(n.hasOwnProperty(l)&&n[l]){var s=n[l];s=Array.isArray(s)?s:[s];for(var u=0;u<s.length;++u){if(o&&o==l+","+u)return;var c=s[u],g=c.inside,f=!!c.lookbehind,h=!!c.greedy,d=0,m=c.alias;if(h&&!c.pattern.global){var p=c.pattern.toString().match(/[imsuy]*$/)[0];c.pattern=RegExp(c.pattern.source,p+"g")}c=c.pattern||c;for(var y=t,v=a;y<r.length;v+=r[y].length,++y){var k=r[y];if(r.length>e.length)return;if(!(k instanceof _)){if(h&&y!=r.length-1){if(c.lastIndex=v,!(S=c.exec(e)))break;for(var b=S.index+(f&&S[1]?S[1].length:0),w=S.index+S[0].length,A=y,P=v,x=r.length;A<x&&(P<w||!r[A].type&&!r[A-1].greedy);++A)(P+=r[A].length)<=b&&(++y,v=P);if(r[y]instanceof _)continue;O=A-y,k=e.slice(v,P),S.index-=v}else{c.lastIndex=0;var S=c.exec(k),O=1}if(S){f&&(d=S[1]?S[1].length:0);w=(b=S.index+d)+(S=S[0].slice(d)).length;var E=k.slice(0,b),N=k.slice(w),j=[y,O];E&&(++y,v+=E.length,j.push(E));var L=new _(l,g?C.tokenize(S,g):S,m,S,h);if(j.push(L),N&&j.push(N),Array.prototype.splice.apply(r,j),1!=O&&C.matchGrammar(e,r,n,y,v,!0,l+","+u),i)break}else if(i)break}}}}},tokenize:function(e,r){var n=[e],t=r.rest;if(t){for(var a in t)r[a]=t[a];delete r.rest}return C.matchGrammar(e,n,r,0,0,!1),n},hooks:{all:{},add:function(e,r){var n=C.hooks.all;n[e]=n[e]||[],n[e].push(r)},run:function(e,r){var n=C.hooks.all[e];if(n&&n.length)for(var t,a=0;t=n[a++];)t(r)}},Token:_};function _(e,r,n,t,a){this.type=e,this.content=r,this.alias=n,this.length=0|(t||"").length,this.greedy=!!a}if(u.Prism=C,_.stringify=function r(e,n){if("string"==typeof e)return e;if(Array.isArray(e)){var t="";return e.forEach(function(e){t+=r(e,n)}),t}var a={type:e.type,content:r(e.content,n),tag:"span",classes:["token",e.type],attributes:{},language:n},i=e.alias;i&&(Array.isArray(i)?Array.prototype.push.apply(a.classes,i):a.classes.push(i)),C.hooks.run("wrap",a);var o="";for(var l in a.attributes)o+=" "+l+'="'+(a.attributes[l]||"").replace(/"/g,"&quot;")+'"';return"<"+a.tag+' class="'+a.classes.join(" ")+'"'+o+">"+a.content+"</"+a.tag+">"},!u.document)return u.addEventListener&&(C.disableWorkerMessageHandler||u.addEventListener("message",function(e){var r=JSON.parse(e.data),n=r.language,t=r.code,a=r.immediateClose;u.postMessage(C.highlight(t,C.languages[n],n)),a&&u.close()},!1)),C;var e=C.util.currentScript();function n(){C.manual||C.highlightAll()}if(e&&(C.filename=e.src,e.hasAttribute("data-manual")&&(C.manual=!0)),!C.manual){var t=document.readyState;"loading"===t||"interactive"===t&&e&&e.defer?document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",n):window.requestAnimationFrame?window.requestAnimationFrame(n):window.setTimeout(n,16)}return C}(_self);"undefined"!=typeof module&&module.exports&&(module.exports=Prism),"undefined"!=typeof global&&(global.Prism=Prism);
Prism.languages.markup={comment:/<!--[\s\S]*?-->/,prolog:/<\?[\s\S]+?\?>/,doctype:{pattern:/<!DOCTYPE(?:[^>"'[\]]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+(?:\[(?:(?!<!--)[^"'\]]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|<!--[\s\S]*?-->)*\]\s*)?>/i,greedy:!0},cdata:/<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?]]>/i,tag:{pattern:/<\/?(?!\d)[^\s>\/=$<%]+(?:\s(?:\s*[^\s>\/=]+(?:\s*=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s'">=]+(?=[\s>]))|(?=[\s/>])))+)?\s*\/?>/i,greedy:!0,inside:{tag:{pattern:/^<\/?[^\s>\/]+/i,inside:{punctuation:/^<\/?/,namespace:/^[^\s>\/:]+:/}},"attr-value":{pattern:/=\s*(?:"[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s'">=]+)/i,inside:{punctuation:[/^=/,{pattern:/^(\s*)["']|["']$/,lookbehind:!0}]}},punctuation:/\/?>/,"attr-name":{pattern:/[^\s>\/]+/,inside:{namespace:/^[^\s>\/:]+:/}}}},entity:/&#?[\da-z]{1,8};/i},Prism.languages.markup.tag.inside["attr-value"].inside.entity=Prism.languages.markup.entity,Prism.hooks.add("wrap",function(a){"entity"===a.type&&(a.attributes.title=a.content.replace(/&amp;/,"&"))}),Object.defineProperty(Prism.languages.markup.tag,"addInlined",{value:function(a,e){var s={};s["language-"+e]={pattern:/(^<!\[CDATA\[)[\s\S]+?(?=\]\]>$)/i,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages[e]},s.cdata=/^<!\[CDATA\[|\]\]>$/i;var n={"included-cdata":{pattern:/<!\[CDATA\[[\s\S]*?\]\]>/i,inside:s}};n["language-"+e]={pattern:/[\s\S]+/,inside:Prism.languages[e]};var t={};t[a]={pattern:RegExp("(<__[\\s\\S]*?>)(?:<!\\[CDATA\\[[\\s\\S]*?\\]\\]>\\s*|[\\s\\S])*?(?=<\\/__>)".replace(/__/g,a),"i"),lookbehind:!0,greedy:!0,inside:n},Prism.languages.insertBefore("markup","cdata",t)}}),Prism.languages.xml=Prism.languages.extend("markup",{}),Prism.languages.html=Prism.languages.markup,Prism.languages.mathml=Prism.languages.markup,Prism.languages.svg=Prism.languages.markup;
!function(s){var e=/("|')(?:\\(?:\r\n|[\s\S])|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/;s.languages.css={comment:/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//,atrule:{pattern:/@[\w-]+[\s\S]*?(?:;|(?=\s*\{))/,inside:{rule:/^@[\w-]+/,"selector-function-argument":{pattern:/(\bselector\s*\((?!\s*\))\s*)(?:[^()]|\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\))+?(?=\s*\))/,lookbehind:!0,alias:"selector"}}},url:{pattern:RegExp("url\\((?:"+e.source+"|[^\n\r()]*)\\)","i"),inside:{function:/^url/i,punctuation:/^\(|\)$/}},selector:RegExp("[^{}\\s](?:[^{};\"']|"+e.source+")*?(?=\\s*\\{)"),string:{pattern:e,greedy:!0},property:/[-_a-z\xA0-\uFFFF][-\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*:)/i,important:/!important\b/i,function:/[-a-z0-9]+(?=\()/i,punctuation:/[(){};:,]/},s.languages.css.atrule.inside.rest=s.languages.css;var t=s.languages.markup;t&&(t.tag.addInlined("style","css"),s.languages.insertBefore("inside","attr-value",{"style-attr":{pattern:/\s*style=("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])*\1/i,inside:{"attr-name":{pattern:/^\s*style/i,inside:t.tag.inside},punctuation:/^\s*=\s*['"]|['"]\s*$/,"attr-value":{pattern:/.+/i,inside:s.languages.css}},alias:"language-css"}},t.tag))}(Prism);
Prism.languages.clike={comment:[{pattern:/(^|[^\\])\/\*[\s\S]*?(?:\*\/|$)/,lookbehind:!0},{pattern:/(^|[^\\:])\/\/.*/,lookbehind:!0,greedy:!0}],string:{pattern:/(["'])(?:\\(?:\r\n|[\s\S])|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/,greedy:!0},"class-name":{pattern:/(\b(?:class|interface|extends|implements|trait|instanceof|new)\s+|\bcatch\s+\()[\w.\\]+/i,lookbehind:!0,inside:{punctuation:/[.\\]/}},keyword:/\b(?:if|else|while|do|for|return|in|instanceof|function|new|try|throw|catch|finally|null|break|continue)\b/,boolean:/\b(?:true|false)\b/,function:/\w+(?=\()/,number:/\b0x[\da-f]+\b|(?:\b\d+\.?\d*|\B\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?/i,operator:/[<>]=?|[!=]=?=?|--?|\+\+?|&&?|\|\|?|[?*/~^%]/,punctuation:/[{}[\];(),.:]/};
Prism.languages.javascript=Prism.languages.extend("clike",{"class-name":[Prism.languages.clike["class-name"],{pattern:/(^|[^$\w\xA0-\uFFFF])[_$A-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\.(?:prototype|constructor))/,lookbehind:!0}],keyword:[{pattern:/((?:^|})\s*)(?:catch|finally)\b/,lookbehind:!0},{pattern:/(^|[^.]|\.\.\.\s*)\b(?:as|async(?=\s*(?:function\b|\(|[$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]|$))|await|break|case|class|const|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|else|enum|export|extends|for|from|function|get|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|interface|let|new|null|of|package|private|protected|public|return|set|static|super|switch|this|throw|try|typeof|undefined|var|void|while|with|yield)\b/,lookbehind:!0}],number:/\b(?:(?:0[xX](?:[\dA-Fa-f](?:_[\dA-Fa-f])?)+|0[bB](?:[01](?:_[01])?)+|0[oO](?:[0-7](?:_[0-7])?)+)n?|(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+n|NaN|Infinity)\b|(?:\b(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+\.?(?:\d(?:_\d)?)*|\B\.(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+)(?:[Ee][+-]?(?:\d(?:_\d)?)+)?/,function:/#?[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*(?:\.\s*(?:apply|bind|call)\s*)?\()/,operator:/--|\+\+|\*\*=?|=>|&&|\|\||[!=]==|<<=?|>>>?=?|[-+*/%&|^!=<>]=?|\.{3}|\?[.?]?|[~:]/}),Prism.languages.javascript["class-name"][0].pattern=/(\b(?:class|interface|extends|implements|instanceof|new)\s+)[\w.\\]+/,Prism.languages.insertBefore("javascript","keyword",{regex:{pattern:/((?:^|[^$\w\xA0-\uFFFF."'\])\s])\s*)\/(?:\[(?:[^\]\\\r\n]|\\.)*]|\\.|[^/\\\[\r\n])+\/[gimyus]{0,6}(?=(?:\s|\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/)*(?:$|[\r\n,.;:})\]]|\/\/))/,lookbehind:!0,greedy:!0},"function-variable":{pattern:/#?[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*[=:]\s*(?:async\s*)?(?:\bfunction\b|(?:\((?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))*\)|[_$a-zA-Z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*)\s*=>))/,alias:"function"},parameter:[{pattern:/(function(?:\s+[_$A-Za-z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*)?\s*\(\s*)(?!\s)(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))+?(?=\s*\))/,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages.javascript},{pattern:/[_$a-z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*(?=\s*=>)/i,inside:Prism.languages.javascript},{pattern:/(\(\s*)(?!\s)(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))+?(?=\s*\)\s*=>)/,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages.javascript},{pattern:/((?:\b|\s|^)(?!(?:as|async|await|break|case|catch|class|const|continue|debugger|default|delete|do|else|enum|export|extends|finally|for|from|function|get|if|implements|import|in|instanceof|interface|let|new|null|of|package|private|protected|public|return|set|static|super|switch|this|throw|try|typeof|undefined|var|void|while|with|yield)(?![$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]))(?:[_$A-Za-z\xA0-\uFFFF][$\w\xA0-\uFFFF]*\s*)\(\s*)(?!\s)(?:[^()]|\([^()]*\))+?(?=\s*\)\s*\{)/,lookbehind:!0,inside:Prism.languages.javascript}],constant:/\b[A-Z](?:[A-Z_]|\dx?)*\b/}),Prism.languages.insertBefore("javascript","string",{"template-string":{pattern:/`(?:\\[\s\S]|\${(?:[^{}]|{(?:[^{}]|{[^}]*})*})+}|(?!\${)[^\\`])*`/,greedy:!0,inside:{"template-punctuation":{pattern:/^`|`$/,alias:"string"},interpolation:{pattern:/((?:^|[^\\])(?:\\{2})*)\${(?:[^{}]|{(?:[^{}]|{[^}]*})*})+}/,lookbehind:!0,inside:{"interpolation-punctuation":{pattern:/^\${|}$/,alias:"punctuation"},rest:Prism.languages.javascript}},string:/[\s\S]+/}}}),Prism.languages.markup&&Prism.languages.markup.tag.addInlined("script","javascript"),Prism.languages.js=Prism.languages.javascript;
Prism.languages.python={comment:{pattern:/(^|[^\\])#.*/,lookbehind:!0},"string-interpolation":{pattern:/(?:f|rf|fr)(?:("""|''')[\s\S]+?\1|("|')(?:\\.|(?!\2)[^\\\r\n])*\2)/i,greedy:!0,inside:{interpolation:{pattern:/((?:^|[^{])(?:{{)*){(?!{)(?:[^{}]|{(?!{)(?:[^{}]|{(?!{)(?:[^{}])+})+})+}/,lookbehind:!0,inside:{"format-spec":{pattern:/(:)[^:(){}]+(?=}$)/,lookbehind:!0},"conversion-option":{pattern:/![sra](?=[:}]$)/,alias:"punctuation"},rest:null}},string:/[\s\S]+/}},"triple-quoted-string":{pattern:/(?:[rub]|rb|br)?("""|''')[\s\S]+?\1/i,greedy:!0,alias:"string"},string:{pattern:/(?:[rub]|rb|br)?("|')(?:\\.|(?!\1)[^\\\r\n])*\1/i,greedy:!0},function:{pattern:/((?:^|\s)def[ \t]+)[a-zA-Z_]\w*(?=\s*\()/g,lookbehind:!0},"class-name":{pattern:/(\bclass\s+)\w+/i,lookbehind:!0},decorator:{pattern:/(^\s*)@\w+(?:\.\w+)*/im,lookbehind:!0,alias:["annotation","punctuation"],inside:{punctuation:/\./}},keyword:/\b(?:and|as|assert|async|await|break|class|continue|def|del|elif|else|except|exec|finally|for|from|global|if|import|in|is|lambda|nonlocal|not|or|pass|print|raise|return|try|while|with|yield)\b/,builtin:/\b(?:__import__|abs|all|any|apply|ascii|basestring|bin|bool|buffer|bytearray|bytes|callable|chr|classmethod|cmp|coerce|compile|complex|delattr|dict|dir|divmod|enumerate|eval|execfile|file|filter|float|format|frozenset|getattr|globals|hasattr|hash|help|hex|id|input|int|intern|isinstance|issubclass|iter|len|list|locals|long|map|max|memoryview|min|next|object|oct|open|ord|pow|property|range|raw_input|reduce|reload|repr|reversed|round|set|setattr|slice|sorted|staticmethod|str|sum|super|tuple|type|unichr|unicode|vars|xrange|zip)\b/,boolean:/\b(?:True|False|None)\b/,number:/(?:\b(?=\d)|\B(?=\.))(?:0[bo])?(?:(?:\d|0x[\da-f])[\da-f]*\.?\d*|\.\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?j?\b/i,operator:/[-+%=]=?|!=|\*\*?=?|\/\/?=?|<[<=>]?|>[=>]?|[&|^~]/,punctuation:/[{}[\];(),.:]/},Prism.languages.python["string-interpolation"].inside.interpolation.inside.rest=Prism.languages.python,Prism.languages.py=Prism.languages.python;
Prism.languages.sql={comment:{pattern:/(^|[^\\])(?:\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|(?:--|\/\/|#).*)/,lookbehind:!0},variable:[{pattern:/@(["'`])(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\1)[^\\])+\1/,greedy:!0},/@[\w.$]+/],string:{pattern:/(^|[^@\\])("|')(?:\\[\s\S]|(?!\2)[^\\]|\2\2)*\2/,greedy:!0,lookbehind:!0},function:/\b(?:AVG|COUNT|FIRST|FORMAT|LAST|LCASE|LEN|MAX|MID|MIN|MOD|NOW|ROUND|SUM|UCASE)(?=\s*\()/i,keyword:/\b(?:ACTION|ADD|AFTER|ALGORITHM|ALL|ALTER|ANALYZE|ANY|APPLY|AS|ASC|AUTHORIZATION|AUTO_INCREMENT|BACKUP|BDB|BEGIN|BERKELEYDB|BIGINT|BINARY|BIT|BLOB|BOOL|BOOLEAN|BREAK|BROWSE|BTREE|BULK|BY|CALL|CASCADED?|CASE|CHAIN|CHAR(?:ACTER|SET)?|CHECK(?:POINT)?|CLOSE|CLUSTERED|COALESCE|COLLATE|COLUMNS?|COMMENT|COMMIT(?:TED)?|COMPUTE|CONNECT|CONSISTENT|CONSTRAINT|CONTAINS(?:TABLE)?|CONTINUE|CONVERT|CREATE|CROSS|CURRENT(?:_DATE|_TIME|_TIMESTAMP|_USER)?|CURSOR|CYCLE|DATA(?:BASES?)?|DATE(?:TIME)?|DAY|DBCC|DEALLOCATE|DEC|DECIMAL|DECLARE|DEFAULT|DEFINER|DELAYED|DELETE|DELIMITERS?|DENY|DESC|DESCRIBE|DETERMINISTIC|DISABLE|DISCARD|DISK|DISTINCT|DISTINCTROW|DISTRIBUTED|DO|DOUBLE|DROP|DUMMY|DUMP(?:FILE)?|DUPLICATE|ELSE(?:IF)?|ENABLE|ENCLOSED|END|ENGINE|ENUM|ERRLVL|ERRORS|ESCAPED?|EXCEPT|EXEC(?:UTE)?|EXISTS|EXIT|EXPLAIN|EXTENDED|FETCH|FIELDS|FILE|FILLFACTOR|FIRST|FIXED|FLOAT|FOLLOWING|FOR(?: EACH ROW)?|FORCE|FOREIGN|FREETEXT(?:TABLE)?|FROM|FULL|FUNCTION|GEOMETRY(?:COLLECTION)?|GLOBAL|GOTO|GRANT|GROUP|HANDLER|HASH|HAVING|HOLDLOCK|HOUR|IDENTITY(?:_INSERT|COL)?|IF|IGNORE|IMPORT|INDEX|INFILE|INNER|INNODB|INOUT|INSERT|INT|INTEGER|INTERSECT|INTERVAL|INTO|INVOKER|ISOLATION|ITERATE|JOIN|KEYS?|KILL|LANGUAGE|LAST|LEAVE|LEFT|LEVEL|LIMIT|LINENO|LINES|LINESTRING|LOAD|LOCAL|LOCK|LONG(?:BLOB|TEXT)|LOOP|MATCH(?:ED)?|MEDIUM(?:BLOB|INT|TEXT)|MERGE|MIDDLEINT|MINUTE|MODE|MODIFIES|MODIFY|MONTH|MULTI(?:LINESTRING|POINT|POLYGON)|NATIONAL|NATURAL|NCHAR|NEXT|NO|NONCLUSTERED|NULLIF|NUMERIC|OFF?|OFFSETS?|ON|OPEN(?:DATASOURCE|QUERY|ROWSET)?|OPTIMIZE|OPTION(?:ALLY)?|ORDER|OUT(?:ER|FILE)?|OVER|PARTIAL|PARTITION|PERCENT|PIVOT|PLAN|POINT|POLYGON|PRECEDING|PRECISION|PREPARE|PREV|PRIMARY|PRINT|PRIVILEGES|PROC(?:EDURE)?|PUBLIC|PURGE|QUICK|RAISERROR|READS?|REAL|RECONFIGURE|REFERENCES|RELEASE|RENAME|REPEAT(?:ABLE)?|REPLACE|REPLICATION|REQUIRE|RESIGNAL|RESTORE|RESTRICT|RETURNS?|REVOKE|RIGHT|ROLLBACK|ROUTINE|ROW(?:COUNT|GUIDCOL|S)?|RTREE|RULE|SAVE(?:POINT)?|SCHEMA|SECOND|SELECT|SERIAL(?:IZABLE)?|SESSION(?:_USER)?|SET(?:USER)?|SHARE|SHOW|SHUTDOWN|SIMPLE|SMALLINT|SNAPSHOT|SOME|SONAME|SQL|START(?:ING)?|STATISTICS|STATUS|STRIPED|SYSTEM_USER|TABLES?|TABLESPACE|TEMP(?:ORARY|TABLE)?|TERMINATED|TEXT(?:SIZE)?|THEN|TIME(?:STAMP)?|TINY(?:BLOB|INT|TEXT)|TOP?|TRAN(?:SACTIONS?)?|TRIGGER|TRUNCATE|TSEQUAL|TYPES?|UNBOUNDED|UNCOMMITTED|UNDEFINED|UNION|UNIQUE|UNLOCK|UNPIVOT|UNSIGNED|UPDATE(?:TEXT)?|USAGE|USE|USER|USING|VALUES?|VAR(?:BINARY|CHAR|CHARACTER|YING)|VIEW|WAITFOR|WARNINGS|WHEN|WHERE|WHILE|WITH(?: ROLLUP|IN)?|WORK|WRITE(?:TEXT)?|YEAR)\b/i,boolean:/\b(?:TRUE|FALSE|NULL)\b/i,number:/\b0x[\da-f]+\b|\b\d+\.?\d*|\B\.\d+\b/i,operator:/[-+*\/=%^~]|&&?|\|\|?|!=?|<(?:=>?|<|>)?|>[>=]?|\b(?:AND|BETWEEN|IN|LIKE|NOT|OR|IS|DIV|REGEXP|RLIKE|SOUNDS LIKE|XOR)\b/i,punctuation:/[;[\]()`,.]/};
!function(){if("undefined"!=typeof self&&self.Prism&&self.document){var i=[],l={},c=function(){};Prism.plugins.toolbar={};var e=Prism.plugins.toolbar.registerButton=function(e,n){var t;t="function"==typeof n?n:function(e){var t;return"function"==typeof n.onClick?((t=document.createElement("button")).type="button",t.addEventListener("click",function(){n.onClick.call(this,e)})):"string"==typeof n.url?(t=document.createElement("a")).href=n.url:t=document.createElement("span"),n.className&&t.classList.add(n.className),t.textContent=n.text,t},e in l?console.warn('There is a button with the key "'+e+'" registered already.'):i.push(l[e]=t)},t=Prism.plugins.toolbar.hook=function(a){var e=a.element.parentNode;if(e&&/pre/i.test(e.nodeName)&&!e.parentNode.classList.contains("code-toolbar")){var t=document.createElement("div");t.classList.add("code-toolbar"),e.parentNode.insertBefore(t,e),t.appendChild(e);var r=document.createElement("div");r.classList.add("toolbar");var n=i,o=function(e){for(;e;){var t=e.getAttribute("data-toolbar-order");if(null!=t)return(t=t.trim()).length?t.split(/\s*,\s*/g):[];e=e.parentElement}}(a.element);o&&(n=o.map(function(e){return l[e]||c})),n.forEach(function(e){var t=e(a);if(t){var n=document.createElement("div");n.classList.add("toolbar-item"),n.appendChild(t),r.appendChild(n)}}),t.appendChild(r)}};e("label",function(e){var t=e.element.parentNode;if(t&&/pre/i.test(t.nodeName)&&t.hasAttribute("data-label")){var n,a,r=t.getAttribute("data-label");try{a=document.querySelector("template#"+r)}catch(e){}return a?n=a.content:(t.hasAttribute("data-url")?(n=document.createElement("a")).href=t.getAttribute("data-url"):n=document.createElement("span"),n.textContent=r),n}}),Prism.hooks.add("complete",t)}}();
```

```css
code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
 color: #ccc;
 background: none;
 font-family: Consolas, Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Ubuntu Mono', monospace;
 font-size: 1em;
 text-align: left;
 white-space: pre;
 word-spacing: normal;
 word-break: normal;
 word-wrap: normal;
 line-height: 1.5;

 -moz-tab-size: 1;
 -o-tab-size: 1;
 tab-size: 1;

 -webkit-hyphens: none;
 -moz-hyphens: none;
 -ms-hyphens: none;
 hyphens: none;

}

/* Code blocks */
pre[class*="language-"] {
 /*padding: 1em;*/
 margin: .5em 0;
 overflow: auto;
}

:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"],
pre[class*="language-"] {
 background: #2d2d2d;
}

/* Inline code */
:not(pre) > code[class*="language-"] {
 padding: .1em;
 border-radius: .3em;
 white-space: normal;
}

.token.comment,
.token.block-comment,
.token.prolog,
.token.doctype,
.token.cdata {
 color: #999;
}

.token.punctuation {
 color: #ccc;
}

.token.tag,
.token.attr-name,
.token.namespace,
.token.deleted {
 color: #e2777a;
}

.token.function-name {
 color: #6196cc;
}

.token.boolean,
.token.number,
.token.function {
 color: #f08d49;
}

.token.property,
.token.class-name,
.token.constant,
.token.symbol {
 color: #f8c555;
}

.token.selector,
.token.important,
.token.atrule,
.token.keyword,
.token.builtin {
 color: #cc99cd;
}

.token.string,
.token.char,
.token.attr-value,
.token.regex,
.token.variable {
 color: #7ec699;
}

.token.operator,
.token.entity,
.token.url {
 color: #67cdcc;
}

.token.important,
.token.bold {
 font-weight: bold;
}
.token.italic {
 font-style: italic;
}

.token.entity {
 cursor: help;
}

.token.inserted {
 color: green;
}

div.code-toolbar {
 position: relative;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar {
 position: absolute;
 top: .3em;
 right: .2em;
 transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
 opacity: 0;
}

div.code-toolbar:hover > .toolbar {
 opacity: 1;
}

/* Separate line b/c rules are thrown out if selector is invalid.
   IE11 and old Edge versions don't support :focus-within. */
div.code-toolbar:focus-within > .toolbar {
 opacity: 1;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar .toolbar-item {
 display: inline-block;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a {
 cursor: pointer;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button {
 background: none;
 border: 0;
 color: inherit;
 font: inherit;
 line-height: normal;
 overflow: visible;
 padding: 0;
 -webkit-user-select: none; /* for button */
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar span {
 color: #bbb;
 font-size: .8em;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background: #f5f2f0;
 background: rgba(224, 224, 224, 0.2);
 box-shadow: 0 2px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 border-radius: .5em;
}

div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a:hover,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar a:focus,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button:hover,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar button:focus,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar span:hover,
div.code-toolbar > .toolbar span:focus {
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="container">
  <div id="expresiones" class="clasificacion">
   <h1>EXPRESIONES</h1>
   <pre>
    <code class="language-python">
    if x < 0:
     x = 0
     print('Negativo cambiado a cero')
    elif x == 0:
     print('Cero')
    elif x == 1:
     print('Simple')
    else:
      print('Más')
    </code>
   </pre>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comparto aquí un enlace a la documentación sobre el uso de 'tab-size' por si te fuera de utilidad en tu proyecto o en otro momento: [W3School - TabSize](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_tab-size.asp)